# Genexus + gridstack

Tags: genexus, gridstack

I'm trying work Gridstack with Genexus UserControls, it's all ok but it's not dragging/resizable.. Gridstack is the best tool I've found to create a dynamic layout, is there any other that I can dimly render the layout?

Comment: Could you please share the URL with a working sample?

Comment: It worked, it was some problem with plugin conflict, but I do not know which one